# Rewriting a Mod Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

So, my host went down recently and I had to move to a new host - but that means my htaccess file got lost in the move...

And now I've got to rewrite it, but it was a crapshoot to begin with...

What I need to do is write the following...

Turn...

```
http://longdomain.com/show.php?id=100
```

into

```
http://shortdomain.com/100
```

So when somebody visits the short URL, it'll load the long URL without changing the actual URL they're at.

This keeps my short URL service separate from the account and URL management sections.

I was using mod proxy for this so I could go cross domain.

I'm at a loss as to how I was doing it though.

Thanks for the help guys...

Comment: As a sidenote: _Use a version control system_!

Comment: Haha, yeah, I learned my lesson this time.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your .htaccess in the root dir of your `shortdomain` site

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if its on shortdoman
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shortdomain\.com$ [NC]
#with a numeric path, proxy to longdomain and stop processing further rules
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ http://longdomain.com/show.php?id=$1 [P,L]
```